# how to find cause of function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

this seems to be some wired question but i need to differentiate between this two.

i have an function

```
function calculatePerDayRentCost(){
//body
}
```

and calling this function by two ways

first(programmatically i means )

```
$('#qtyExtraDriver').change();
```

second (on changing value of dropdown)

```
<select onchange="calculatePerDayRentCost()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

is there any way to differentiate in between function the cause of function call, that is programmatically or dropdown change.

Comment: [Function caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) or parameter passing. I.E `calculatePerDayRentCost("fromDropDown")`

Comment: @Adelin they're triggering the change event, not directly calling the function.  That won't help them.

Comment: @Archer but you know that they trigger the change event if the function gets an `undefined` instead of `"fromDropDown"`, no?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in it and see the stack trace

Comment: @Adelin Okay I see your point, but there's nothing to stop it being triggered in code without a parameter, so if the OP is happy with that then fine, but I personally wouldn't be.

Comment: Pass the event object from the inline handler (or rather attach the event with jQuery, as it seems you're already using it anyway), and in `calculatePerDayRentCost`, check if the event object exists.

Comment: It's not clear how `$('#qtyExtraDriver').change();` causes `calculatePerDayRentCost` to be called.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Because that triggers the change event and there's an inline handler assignment.  He's basically asking how to differentiate between the select value changing and triggering the change handler through code.

Comment: @Archer yes that's correct. i have tried by managing it using global variable but `$('#qtyExtraDriver').change();` is on multiple places so it do not work for me

Comment: Do you only want to know when it was triggered by the dropdown change?  If so then see what @Adelin posted above as that will do that for you.

Comment: @Archer i have tried `Function caller` but it return's me `function onchange(event) {
  calculatePerDayRentCost(this.value,'infantPerdatRate','infantRentCost',7)
}` in both condition

Comment: You have jQuery - get rid of the nasty inline event handler!

Comment: @Adelin i have tried both the way you mention `Function caller` returning me  `function onchange(event) { calculatePerDayRentCost(this.value,'infantPerdatRate','infantRentCost',7) }` always

Answer (score 3):

You can't differentiate between the inline event handler being triggered by a user or by code, but you can if you assign the handler in code instead...

```js
function calculatePerDayRentCost(e) {
  if (e && e.originalEvent) {
    console.log("fired from select");
  }
  else {
    console.log("fired from code");
  }
}

$(function() {

  // assign the change event handler
  $("#qtyExtraDriver").on("change", function(e) {
    calculatePerDayRentCost(e);
  });

  // trigger the change event through code
  $('#qtyExtraDriver').change();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="qtyExtraDriver">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This uses the `event.originalEvent` property which is a jQuery property that is the original event that triggered the handler.  In the case of actually using the select, it is the change event that triggered the jQuery change event, but when you trigger `.change()` through code, there is no event so it is `undefined`.

**Please Note:** This only works because you're using jQuery to trigger the event, which means we can also use it to handle the event.  If you weren't using jQuery then this answer would be of no use to you.  Just bear this in mind, if you decide to stop using jQuery at any point.

Comment: I think it would help to prevent `Cannot read property 'originalEvent' of undefined`

Comment: @Adelin - where do you see that?

Comment: @Adelin That's not in scope of the question so not relevant, but I've handled a null parameter being passed to the function now.